# Why is there an error on this line of Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

There is a code that on this line of code

```
 Boo.prototype.initone (a) { <-- Syntax error
```

I want to create a simple object of Boo with one property this.bar why would this be giving me an error? The error is listed below which is an uncaught Syntax Error but I am not seeing it.

I know that syntax errors should not be posted but I am just not seeing what is completely wrong with this code below.

Error Code Here:

```
 Boo.prototype.initone (a) {
     this.bar = a;
     return this;
 }
```

Error

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Code:

```
<script>
function Test1() {
}

function Boo () {
    this.bar = 'Test This Method';
}

Boo.prototype.initone (a) {
    this.bar = a;
    return this;
}

Boo.prototype.inittwo (b) {
    this.bar = 'something to do with ' + b;
    return this;
}

var a = new Boo().initone('constructor 1');
var b = new Boo().inittwo('constructor 2');
</script>
```

Code: This code will still show an uncaught exception. If I take the return this out then no error will occur on initone but inittwo seems to be ok.

```
Boo.prototype.initone = function (a) {
    this.bar = a;
    return this;
}

Boo.prototype.inittwo = function (b) {
    this.bar = 'something to do with ' + b;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Make it `Boo.prototype.initone = function(a) {`

Comment: What made you think that `Boo.prototype.initone (a) { }` would define a function?

Comment: Your updated code will not throw a SyntaxError. If it does, then there's some other problem outside that code. Or is it a different error? If you're in strict mode, it's possible for the value of `this` to be `null` or `undefined`, which would result in a TypeError.

Comment: ...the `return` certainly won't be a SyntaxError.

Comment: The code in your question runs with no exceptions ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9crvJ/)). If you're still getting errors, we need to see more of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error here because JavaScript doesn't know *what* you want to do. If you're defining a function, you need to specify it with the `function` keyword.

In this case, it needs to be written as:

```
Boo.prototype.initone = function(a) {
    this.bar = a;
    return this;
}
```

You'll also need to make the change on your `inittwo` method.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's not how you define a function on an object in JS :)

You have to use an equals sign:

```
Foo.prototype.initone = function(bar){
}
```

I think you are remembering the syntax for defining a function like so:

```
function f() { }
```